# Trouble understanding javascript syntax: if (parameter == "someValue") parameter = ""

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, conditional-operator

I'm having trouble understanding this JS syntax:

```
function myFunction(a) {
  if (a == "someValue") a = ""; 
}
```

Is this some sort of shorthand? As in: if "a" is equal to "someValue", then set "a" to be empty?

Comment: Seems like a valid thing to do.

Comment: @adiga so it is a shorthand?

Comment: Maybe shorthand in the sense there are no curly braces (`if (a == "someValue") { a = "" }`).

Comment: @SamiHult thanks, that's all I needed to know. Just wasn't aware that the curly braces can be omitted like this.

Comment: single line statement does not require curly braces.

Comment: The `{...}` are not part of the `if` statement, they are a statement on their own, called a [**block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a standard `if statement` without the curly braces. Your code is basically the same as this:

```
if (a == "someValue") {
  a = "";
}
```

A shorthand would be using something like a **[ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)** like this:

```
a = (a == "someValue") ? "" : a;

// if "a" is loosely equal to "someValue", then assign an empty string to "a",
// else leave "a" unchanged by assigning it to it's current value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to

```js
function myFunction(a) {
  if (a == "someValue")
  {
     a = ""; 
     
  }
}
```

if value of parameter passed to myFunction is "someValue" then set parameter to empty string